# Extracting week in the year with openrefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I would like to extract the week in the year from a large dataset. I selected 'Add column based on this column' and used this script '
value.toDate("yyyy/mm/dd").datePart("weeks")
'

[image: See attached image]

However the result is week in the month but not year.

Comment: I tried to transform the column to date with "value.toDate()" and then used this GREL "value.toDate('yyyy-mm-ddh:m:s').toString('w')". That seemed to work.

Comment: But we still got "week in month" using `value.toDate('y/m/d').toString('w')`. According to the [SimpleDateFormat patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it should be "week in year".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More about this issue [here](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/2406). Until it is solved, could you switch to Python/Jython and use this script?

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(value, '%Y/%m/%d')

return date_time_obj.isocalendar()[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the bug. I tried an alternative workaround it seemed to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036538/extracting-week-in-the-year-with-openrefine#comment109722916_62036538

Comment: @Arky Nice catch!